# How to provide default values for Symfony bundle parameters / config values?

Tags: symfony, composer-php, autowired

I have created a Symfony 5.3+ bundle which should be used to add common code to different projects. The bundle contains some services which should be configurable using parameters / options as described in the Symfony docs.

**How to provide default values for these options?** Defaults set in the bundles `Configuration.php` do not have any effect.

---

**Details:**

I have created a bundle project using the following structure and added it to my Symfony project using composer:

```
path/to/bundles/XYCommonsBundle/
    config/
        services.yaml
    src/
        Service/
            SomeService.php
        DependencyInjection
            Configuration.php
            XYCommensExtension.php
    XYCommensBundle.php
    composer.json
    ...


// src/DependencyInjection/XYCommensExtension.php
<?php

namespace XY\CommensBundle\DependencyInjection;

use ...

class XYCommensExtension extends Extension {
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container) {
        $configuration = new Configuration();
        $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

        // make config available as parameters. Necessary?
        foreach ($config as $key => $value) {
            $container->setParameter('xy_commons.' . $key, $value);
        }


        $loader = new YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../../config'));
        $loader->load('services.yaml');
    }
}


// src/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php
class Configuration implements ConfigurationInterface {
    public function getConfigTreeBuilder() {
        $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder('xy_commons');
        
        $treeBuilder->getRootNode()
            ->children()
                ->arrayNode('params')
                    ->children()
                        ->integerNode('paramA')->defaultValue(100)->end()
                        ->integerNode('ParamB')->defaultValue(200)->end()
                    ->end()
                ->end()
            ->end()
        ;
        
        return $treeBuilder;
    }
}


// config/services.yaml
services:
    xy_commons.service.some_service:
        class:  XY\CommonsBundle\Service\SomeService
        arguments:   
            - $paramA: '%xy_commons.params.paramA%'
            - $paramB: '%xy_commons.params.paramB%' 


// src/Service/SomeService.php
<?php

namespace XY\CommensBundle\Service;

use ...

class SomeService {
    public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger, $paramA, $paramB) {
}
```

### Problem: How to use default values of parameters?

`paramA` and `paramB` are defined in the bundles `Configuration.php` with default values of 100 and 200. I would like to use these defaults in the project without specifying custom values. However, I do not create a `config/packages/xy_commons.yaml` file in the project and explicitly specify values, I get the following error:

> You have requested a non-existent parameter
> "xy_commons.params.paramA".

When creating a `config/packages/xy_commons.yaml` file, I cannot use `~` to use the default value:

```
xy_commons:
    params:
        paramA: ~
        paramB: ~
```

> Invalid type for path "xy_commons.params.paramA". Expected "int", but
> got "null".

Only when explicitly specifying a value it works:

```
xy_commons:
    params:
        paramA: 300
        paramB: 400
```

**How to use the default values defined in `Configuration.php`?**

Comment: Please do not ask multiple questions in a single question. Also, why not ship a configuration file with your bundle that contains these parameters, like many other bundles do?

Comment: @Cerad the `Configuration` class is already in the question... Or do you mean something different?

Comment: Just for info, I deleted my comments and posted an answer.  I did not notice that the Configuration object was in the question.  Scrolling issues.  So my comments did not make much sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three problems here.  The first deals with what is possibly my least favorite class in Symfony.  The dreaded configuration object.  In particular, you need to use [addDefaultsIfNotSet](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/config/definition.html#array-node-options) when dealing with arrays:

```
class Configuration implements ConfigurationInterface 
{
  public function getConfigTreeBuilder() 
  {
      $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder('my');

      $rootNode = $treeBuilder->getRootNode();

      $rootNode
          ->children()
              ->arrayNode('params')->addDefaultsIfNotSet() # ADD THIS
                  ->children()
                      ->integerNode('paramA')->defaultValue(100)->end()
                      ->integerNode('paramB')->defaultValue(200)->end()
                  ->end()
              ->end()
          ->end()
      ;
      
      return $treeBuilder;
  }
}
```

The second problem is that you are not defining your parameters correctly.  In particular the parameters will be grouped in an array called params.  You almost had it:

```
class MyExtension extends Extension
{
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $configuration = new Configuration();
        $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

        foreach($config['params'] as $key => $value) {
           $container->setParameter('xy_commons.params.' . $key, $value);
        }

# Use bin/console dump:container --parameters to verify
```

The final thing is the use of tilde to indicate default values.  I think this might be a works as designed issue.  Technically, tilde on yaml means null and it is up to the processor to get it a meaning.  The ArrayNode works as expected but the IntegerNode does not.  So this works:

```
# config/packages/my.yaml
my:
    params: ~
#        paramA: ~
#        paramB: 666
```